# Get google maps getplace lat and long

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps api in localhost for address auto completion. The address fetching fine, However, i would like to fetch the lat/lon as well, but my code no longer work, what to do ?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true"></script>
```

```js
place = places.getPlace();
address = place.formatted_address;
latitude = place.geometry.location.H;
longitude = place.geometry.location.L;
```

Cheers all

Comment: You no longer need to pass the `sensor` attribute in the URL when loading the Maps JS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always reference the latitude and longitude properties of the `place.geometry.location` object like this:

```js
var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

The PlaceGeometry class's `location` property is a LatLng object:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceGeometry
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

The `H` and `L` properties are undocumented, and are liable to change with every new release of the Maps API, and shouldn't be used.